ROS2 cartographer
I'm using ros2 cartographer for localisation purpose.
Below are following things that i have done until now.

I have mapping using slam tool box.
ros2 service call /write_state cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/WriteState "{filename: 'map_nv25_v1.pdstream',include_unfinished_submaps : false}"
(I have used this code to save the map as .pbstream)
For some strange reason when i try to save .pbstream (map) while running gazebo simulation  and upload it during localisation,I can see the map in rviz2 but when i do the same process using real robot i cant find map in rviz2.

below is my cartographer configuration
ROBOT.lua
include "map_builder.lua"
include "trajectory_builder.lua"

options = {
  map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
  trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
  map_frame = "map",
  tracking_frame = "base_link",
  published_frame = "base_footprint",
  odom_frame = "filtered_odometry",
  provide_odom_frame = true,
  publish_frame_projected_to_2d = false,
  use_pose_extrapolator = true,
  use_odometry = false,
  use_nav_sat = false,
  use_landmarks = false,
  num_laser_scans = 1,
  num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,
  num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 10,
  num_point_clouds = 0,
  lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,
  submap_publish_period_sec = 0.3,
  pose_publish_period_sec = 5e-3,
  trajectory_publish_period_sec = 30e-3,
  rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  odometry_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  imu_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.,
}

MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_2d = true
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.num_accumulated_range_data = 10

return options

sid_localization.lua
include "ROBOT.lua"

TRAJECTORY_BUILDER.pure_localization_trimmer = {
  max_submaps_to_keep = 3,
}
POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes = 20

return options

Launch file to run cartographer
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import ThisLaunchFileDir


def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')
    turtlebot3_cartographer_prefix = get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_cartographer')
    cartographer_config_dir = LaunchConfiguration('cartographer_config_dir', default=os.path.join(
                                                  turtlebot3_cartographer_prefix, 'config'))
    configuration_basename = LaunchConfiguration('configuration_basename',
                                                 default='turtlebot3_lds_2d.lua')

    resolution = LaunchConfiguration('resolution', default='0.05')
    publish_period_sec = LaunchConfiguration('publish_period_sec', default='1.0')

  #  rviz_config_dir = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_cartographer'),
                                 #  'rviz', 'tb3_cartographer.rviz')

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'cartographer_config_dir',
            default_value=cartographer_config_dir,
            description='Full path to config file to load'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'configuration_basename',
            default_value=configuration_basename,
            description='Name of lua file for cartographer'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

        Node(
            package='cartographer_ros',
            executable='cartographer_node',
            name='cartographer_node',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
            arguments=['-configuration_directory', cartographer_config_dir,
                       '-configuration_basename', configuration_basename]),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'resolution',
            default_value=resolution,
            description='Resolution of a grid cell in the published occupancy grid'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'publish_period_sec',
            default_value=publish_period_sec,
            description='OccupancyGrid publishing period'),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/occupancy_grid.launch.py']),
            launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 'resolution': resolution,
                              'publish_period_sec': publish_period_sec}.items(),
        ),

